# toggle a flex div with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to toggle a div with jQuery, the twist is my div is a flex container.

Is there a jquery function equivalent to `.toggle()` that would toggle between `display:none;` and `display:flex;` instead of the standard that goes between `display:none` and `display:block;`

Comment: I would like to understand the down votes...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The best or better way to handle this is using `.toggleClass()` and use the `hidden` class, if you are using bootstrap or just create a new class.

```js
$(function () {
  setInterval(function () {
    $(".flexbox").toggleClass("hidden");
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flexbox">FlexBox</div>
```

This way the `display` and other properties are always maintained and also there will be a less clutter in the inline CSS generated by jQuery (who cares about that anyway).

Answer (score 4):

From [Jquery API](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) -

> The display property is saved and restored as needed. If an element
>   has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once
>   again be displayed inline.

The same applies with "flex" as would with inline.

So if the elements css is

```
display: flex;
```

when toggled it will remain a flexbox when visible.

If you need the element hidden from when the page loads, you may need to use another solution such as the current [accepted answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53427485/8472295) or a workaround would be to trigger a toggle to hide it with jQuery when the page loads(but that may not be the best practice in my opinion)

Comment: at the time of asking, this was not working. I have indeed found since then that it now works as I need.

Comment: This is simply incorrect because VERY OFTEN situations arise where the flex item is toggled off by another function and the style becomes {style: display: none}  when you then click the toggle button it inserts the css {style: display:block} simply assuming that you want a block.  This answer simply does not recognize the situation.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a normal div (block) before the flex div and toggle it. This will do the trick you need.

Try the example! Thank you :)

```js
 function toggleAreaData(){
    jQuery( "#toggler" ).toggle( "#toggler" );
  }
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Toggle a flex with toggle()!
<br>
<br>
<!-- toggle container block -->
<div id="toggler"> 
  <div style="display:flex;">
     MY FLEX TOGGLE DATA<br>
     MY FLEX TOGGLE DATA
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<!-- toggle button -->
<button onclick="toggleAreaData()">PRESS TO TOGGLE</button>

<br>
<br>
So just use a div block inside a div flex :)
</html>
```

Comment: interesting answer though it adds to the number of DOM in the page which is not exactly a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me if you want the div hidden to start with.

```
<style>
    #info-top-button {
        width: 4em;
        height: 2em;
        margin: 0.7em;
    }
    #info-top {
        /* SET DISPLAY IN CSS */
        display: flex;
    }
</style>

<script>
    jQuery("document").ready(function() {
        // SET DISPLAY TO NONE BEFORE ADDING CLICK FUNCTION //
        jQuery("#info-top").css("display","none"); 
        jQuery('#info-top-button').click( () => {
            jQuery("#info-top").toggle(500);
        });
    });
</script>

<button class="btn" id="info-top-button">INFO</button>
<div id="info-top">
Some info!.
</div>
```